# Where is the error message for Remmina on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rdp

I am trying to use Remmina on Ubuntu 20.04 to connect to my Windows 10 PC via Remote Gateway Server but I keep getting "Cannot connect to the RDP server". I would like to see the detailed error message but I don't know where to find it on Ubuntu. Sorry I am still a noobie Ubuntu user. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can see logs in : `/var/log/user.log`

Answer (score 4):

Even this is old question, the answer is:

Edit host's, that you want to connect to, options.

- right click and Edit
- go to Advanced tab
- choose `FreeRDP` log level
- click Save

Then open debugging window.

- click three dots Menu (in my case) on the right top of Remmina main window
- choose Debugging

Now try connect to host and check the debugging window while it will be filling up with information.

Comment: I'm using Remmina 1.4.25, and I don't have an option called "FreeRDP log level" under the Advanced tab...?